# Is $(\mathbb K[x], \jmath)$ the free vector space over $\mathbb N$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field and $\mathbb N$ be the set of natural numbers. Let:

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\jmath:& \mathbb N&\longrightarrow & \mathbb K[x]\\ & n& \longmapsto & x^n, 
\end{array}$$
where $\mathbb K[x]$ is the $\mathbb K$-vector spaces of polynomials with coefficientes in $\mathbb K$. Am I right to think that $(\mathbb K[x], \jmath)$ is the free vector space over $\mathbb N$?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, $(\Bbb{K}[x], \jmath)$ is one way of defining the free $\Bbb{K}$-vector space over $\Bbb{N}$. What thoughts do you have about what this means and how to prove it?

Comment: Well, given any map $\varphi:\mathbb N\longrightarrow V$ from $\mathbb N$ to a vector space $V$, we could define the linear map $\overline{\varphi}: \mathbb K[x]\longrightarrow V$ on a basis element as $\overline{\varphi}(x^n):=\varphi(n)$ so that $\overline{\varphi}\circ \jmath=\varphi$. This shows the pair $(\mathbb K[x], \jmath)$ is universal. The uniqueness from $\overline{\varphi}$ is clear.

Comment: @RobArthan do you have any other interesting examples from free vector spaces?

Comment: apart from classical constructions such as the tensor product, etc.

Comment: I really don't know what else you are looking for: your first comment shows that you understand why the answer to your question is yes. As for other interesting examples, well any $\Bbb{K}$-vector space with a countably infinite basis will do

Comment: I just wanted to check that fact. I researched about it and this example $(\mathbb K[x], \jmath)$ never appeared when free vector spaces are dealt.